# Renaming/Modifying using current name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, i tried to modify a text shown below with **substring** command.

eg. "**ABCD_X_DD_text**" into "ABCD-X(DD)_text" this

i used this

```
var str = "ABCD_X_DD_cover";
var res = str.substring(0,4)+"-"+str.substring(5,6)+"("+str.substring(7,9)+")"+str.substring(9,15);
// print to console
console.log(res);
```

i got what i want. But problem is X and DD are numerical (digit) value. and they are changeable. here my code just stop working.

it can be ..... "ABCD_XXX_DDDD_text"  or "ABCD_X_DDD_text".

could you suggest some code, which works well in this situation.

Comment: Use regular expressions, you can't make it with substring since you don't know how many positions you need to substract. With regular expressions you can detect the number (doesn't matter its length) and then replace with all you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **split** of the words.

```js
var strArray = [
  "ABCD_X_DD_cover",
  "ABCD_XX_DD_cover",
  "ABCD_XXX_DD_cover"
];

for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
  var split = strArray[i].split("_");
  var str = split[0] + "-" + split[1] + "(" + split[2] + ") " + split[3];
  console.log(str);
}
```

I used a **for** cycle using an **array** of strings, but you can do it with a variable too.

Comment: Thanks Guys, for your support.